# AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'serialize'

Tags: django

I am trying to serialize model instance as i can't reach out the url or the details of the 'followiing' model.

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import update_last_login
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from django.core import serializers
from rest_framework import serializers
from urllib import request
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny,IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from django.http import HttpResponse



class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    jsonfollowing = serializers.serialize('json', [ followiing ,])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username','password','followiing','jsonfollowing')
```

But i get the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'serialize'
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are trying to [`serialize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/) from *django.core*, but you are overriding the *django.core* import with *rest_framework*, so use of `as` should do the job:

```
from django.core import serializers as core_serializers
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import update_last_login
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from django.core import serializers
from rest_framework import serializers
from urllib import request
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny,IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from django.http import HttpResponse

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    jsonfollowing = core_serializers.serialize('json', [ followiing ,])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username','password','followiing','jsonfollowing')
```

Comment: now i get this error ```NameError: name 'followiing' is not defined```

Comment: I think it should be `following` not `followiing`

Comment: ìn models it is defined as followiing(i had some unknown clashes with some other models etc.. so i had to define it like that),so there is no typing error.It gives me same error when i try other models.

Comment: anyways,the main issue is solved so i am closing this case.Thank you!